# How to stub require.js module in Backbone initialize method

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine

Hello I want to be able to stub requirejs modules that get called in the initialize of a Backbone object. For example:

```
define(function(require){
    var Backbone = require("backbone"),
    BalanceModule = require("BalanceModule");

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:  function(){
            this.balance = BalanceModule.requestBalance();
        }
    });
})
```

I want to be able to stub the BalanceModule but because is in the initialize method I am not able to.

I could stub the initialize method but then it means that I have the code to be tested in the tests.

I tried to require.undef() the module and load another one with no luck. It seems that once you have the object initialised it has an internal reference not able to override.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your *BalanceModule* like this:

```
define({        
    var BalanceModule = function(){

    }

    return BalanceModule;    
});
```

Instead of:

```
define({        
    var BalanceModule = function(){

    }

    return new BalanceModule();    
});
```

So you can use like this:

```
define(function(require){
    var Backbone = require("backbone"),
    BalanceModule = require("BalanceModule");

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:  function(){
            this.balance = new BalanceModule().requestBalance();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: hmmm, I think you're right. I found that returning new in a AMD module it creates something like a singleton and it was quite convenient. But  I might be shooting myself in the foot here. Let me have a thought